# Local - No video with supported format and MIME type found in Mozila Firebox

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mozilla, mime

I have hundred video in local web page, that all are videos added inside of bootstrap modal content, modal will open and video playing when click static image, here few video played well in Mozilla Firebox, Those remaining videos not played in Mozilla Firebox and not on Google Chrome. it mozila shows error "no video with support format and MIME type found",

Those whole video details,

```
        type - video

        codec - H264 - MPEG-4 AVC video, AAC audio

        Resolution - 1280 x 720
```

So find the solution why few video not play in Mozilla Firebox ?[image]

Html

```
<div class="modal-body">                      
   <video  controls>
        <source  id="Video1" src="video/video1.Mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>            
</div>
.
.
<div class="modal-body">                      
   <video  controls>
        <source  id="Video2" src="video/video2.Mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>            
</div>
.
.
.
<div class="modal-body">                  
    <video  controls>
        <source  id="Video100" src="video/video100.Mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>            
</div>
```

Comment: MP4 in firefox relies on OS libraries or plugins - see: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox. This can cause problems if the library is not present in your OS for some reason.

Comment: i am using codec - H264 - MPEG-4 AVC video, AAC audio format only, that format accepted in Mozilla , here more then 100 video is there,  few video played well in Mozilla Firebox, Those remaining videos not played in Mozilla Firebox, i don't know why ?, i thing it may be memory problem in Mozilla

Comment: If you are able to provide a link to one of the videos which does not play it may be possible to look further.

Comment: I find the solution for that issue, i did change format  like that video1.webm instead of video1.mp4, its working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually problem was used Mp4 format. if used Mp4 format at Mozilla Firebox some limited videos only played without error in local machine, some videos link got the error Message

So Change the video1.webm format instead of video1.Mp4 format. its working fine, and change the type also  type="video/webm".

```
    <div class="modal-body">                      
           <video  controls>
                <source  id="Video1" src="video/video1.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>            
        </div>
        .
        .
        <div class="modal-body">                      
           <video  controls>
                <source  id="Video2" src="video/video2.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>            
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
        <div class="modal-body">                  
            <video  controls>
                <source  id="Video100" src="video/video100.webm" type="video/webm">
            </video>            
        </div>
```